# Why the wso2 esb Web Service proxy made my endpoint 'localhost' in WSDL?

Tags: spring, proxy, cxf, wso2, wso2-esb

I created a web service with CXF and Spring support. The direct accessing is successful.
I then ran a WSO2 ESB and created a proxy service to that web service. Calling to the proxied service is failure.
I printed the proxied WSDL and found that the endpoints in that file were all 'localhost'.
I guess the problem is typical but I cannot find any information to help. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit you `axis2.xml` where you find the parameter "WSDLPrefix" for both http and https transport.

```
<parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">http://myhost:8280</parameter>
```

This will create your Proxy endpoints correctly.

Complete information at: http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/admin_guide.html#HostPort

P.S. I think Wso2ESB 4.5.0 is 'smarter' and does not need to modify these parameters. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll go and check it out.

Answer (score 2):

also you can specified in carbon.xml the parameter:

```
<HostName>yourhost</HostName>
```

yourhost = ip or name of your server

you can see this info in carbon.xml file:

```
<!--
   Host name or IP address of the machine hosting this server
   e.g. www.wso2.org, 192.168.1.10
   This is will become part of the End Point Reference of the
   services deployed on this server instance.
-->
```

Comment: The description explains this parameter well. It's also the one I need. Thanks.